# Combine elements in list in python

Tags: python, list

I was working with padding of ngram models. My code is like this.

```
n = 5
text = "hello how are"
tokens = text[-n:]
prefix = tokens[:-1]
toPad = (n) - len(prefix)-1
prefix = "<s>"*toPad+tokens
print(list(prefix))
```

which gives me output `['w', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e']` which is correct for me. But when the input text is `"he"` it gives me output `['<', 's', '>', '<', 's', '>', '<', 's', '>', 'h', 'e']`.

But instead of this, my desired output is

```
['<s>', '<s>', '<s>', 'h', 'e']
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `prefix` is a string it the function list() will tokenise it to a list of characters and since `<s>` is a string it will split it into `['<','s','>']`.
You can generate a list in a loop like:

```
n = 5
text = "he"
tokens = text[-n:]
prefix = tokens[:-1]
toPad = (n) - len(prefix)-1
prefix = "<s>"*toPad+tokens
prefList = []
i = 0
while i < len(prefix):
    if prefix[i] == "<":
        prefList.append("<s>")
        i += 3
    else:
        prefList.append(prefix[i])
        i += 1

print(prefList)
```

Output: `['<s>', '<s>', '<s>', 'h', 'e']`

Answer (score 1):

Using findall from regex to create list, rather than list

**Code**

```
import re

def parse(text):
  n = 5
  tokens = text[-n:]
  prefix = tokens[:-1]
  toPad = (n) - len(prefix)-1
  prefix = "<s>"*toPad+tokens

  # Use regex findall to create list
  return re.findall(r'<s>|.', prefix)  # Creates list of either <s> or any character
```

**Test**

```
print(parse("hello how are"))  # ['w', ' ', 'a', 'r', 'e']
print(parse("he"))             # ['<s>', '<s>', '<s>', 'h', 'e']
```